# SQLite, BeautifulSoup, Table Parse -> to List -> to Sqlite Problems

Tags: python, sqlite, beautifulsoup, html-table

EDIT!: i will explain what i want to achieve. i got this code that scrap data from main search page. http://pastebin.com/c6hRN6ac . It Searches the main page for divs with data that i want. then i assign them to var name,year,engine,mileage and other.

`data = [name,year,engine,mileage,link,transm,status,price]`

this list of text data goes to

`conn.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",data)`

it works as i planned.( on the main search page there less data then in detail car page )

Now i am fetching all the car id links combining them with page url, and trying to loop each car id for detail information, with this code http://pastebin.com/hRkmMkHZ

now `def get_car_id():` works. the problem is in `def cars_info():`

I want to use the same concept that i got in my first code  with:

`data = [name,year,engine,mileage,link,transm,status,price]`

`conn.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",data)`

Now the second code gives me an output:

```
[' მწარმოებელი :  BMW']
[' მოდელი :  M3 ']
[' გამოშვების წელი :  2003 / 03']
[' კატეგორია :  სედანი']
[' საწვავის ტიპი :  ბენზინი']
[' ძრავის მოცულობა :  3200 ']
[' გარბენი :  141 კმ.']
[' ცილინდრები :  8']
[' გადაცემათა კოლოფი :  მექანიკური']
[' წამყვანი თვლები :  უკანა']
[' კარები :  4/5']
[' საჭე :  მარცხნივ']
[' მანქანის ფერი :  ნაცრისფერი']
[' სალონის ფერი :  შავი']
[' აირბეგი :  8']
['VIN :  WBS-BL91000JP85609']

[' მწარმოებელი :  MERCEDES-BENZ']
[' მოდელი :  S 320 ']
[' გამოშვების წელი :  2001']
[' კატეგორია :  სედანი']
[' საწვავის ტიპი :  გაზი/ბენზინი']
[' ძრავის მოცულობა :  3200 ']
[' გარბენი :  160000 კმ.']
[' ცილინდრები :  6']
[' გადაცემათა კოლოფი :  ტიპტრონიკი']
[' წამყვანი თვლები :  უკანა']
[' კარები :  4/5']
[' საჭე :  მარჯვნივ']
[' მანქანის ფერი :  შავი']
[' სალონის ფერი :  შავი']
[' აირბეგი :  12']
['VIN : ']

[' მწარმოებელი :  HONDA']
[' მოდელი :  Cr-v ']
[' გამოშვების წელი :  2003']
[' კატეგორია :  ჯიპი']
[' საწვავის ტიპი :  ბენზინი']
[' ძრავის მოცულობა :  2400 ']
[' გარბენი :  267200 კმ.']
[' ცილინდრები :  4']
[' გადაცემათა კოლოფი :  ავტომატიკა']
[' წამყვანი თვლები :  4x4']
[' კარები :  4/5']
[' საჭე :  მარცხნივ']
[' მანქანის ფერი :  ლურჯი']
[' სალონის ფერი :  შავი']
[' აირბეგი :  4']
['VIN : ']

[' მწარმოებელი :  BMW']
[' მოდელი :  325 ']
[' გამოშვების წელი :  2003']
[' კატეგორია :  სედანი']
[' საწვავის ტიპი :  ბენზინი']
[' ძრავის მოცულობა :  2500 ']
[' გარბენი :  169 კმ.']
[' ცილინდრები :  6']
[' გადაცემათა კოლოფი :  მექანიკური']
[' წამყვანი თვლები :  4x4']
[' კარები :  4/5']
[' საჭე :  მარცხნივ']
[' მანქანის ფერი :  ცისფერი']
[' სალონის ფერი :  შავი']
[' აირბეგი :  8']
['VIN : ']
```

One car details ends with `VIN`

now how can i use the same concept to save data for each car in a list like this

`data = [('BMW','M3','2003 / 03','სედანი','ბენზინი','3200','141 კმ.','8','მექანიკური','უკანა','4/5','მარცხნი','ნაცრისფერი','შავი','8','WBS-BL91000JP85609') , ('MERCEDES-BENZ','S 320','2001','სედანი','გაზი/ბენზინი','3200','160000 კმ.','6','ტიპტრონიკი','უკანა','4/5','მარჯვნივ','შავი','შავი','12','')]`

and so for other cars that i got in `def get_car_id()`

so i can insert data to database with this code

`conn.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",data)`

HTML Looks like this:

```
<tr>
        <th class="th-left">
            <div class="th-key"> Manufacturer</div>
            <div class="th-value"> NISSAN</div>
        </th>
        <th class="th-right">
            <div class="th-key"> ABS</div>
            <div class="th-value"><i class='fa fa-check'></i></div>
        </th>
        </tr>
    <tr>
    <th class="th-left">
        <div class="th-key"> Model</div>
        <div class="th-value"> X-Trail </div>
    </th>
    <th class="th-right">
        <div class="th-key"> El. Windows</div>
        <div class="th-value"><i class='fa fa-check'></i></div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="th-left">
        <div class="th-key"> Prod. Year</div>
        <div class="th-value"> 2002</div>
    </th>
    <th class="th-right">
        <div class="th-key"> Air Condintioner</div>
        <div class="th-value"><i class='fa fa-check'></i></div>
    </th>
  </tr>
```

i am doing only `<th class="th-left">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the values separately, pull the values using the divs:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(h)

for row in soup.select("table tr th"):
    a, b = row.select_one("div.th-key"), row.select_one("div.th-value")
    print a.text,b.text
```

Which gives you all the data:

```
Manufacturer NISSAN
ABS 
Model X-Trail
El. Windows 
Prod. Year 2002
Air Condintioner 
Category Jeep
Climate System 
Fuel Type Gas/Petrol
Leather interior 
Engine Volume 2000
Disks: 
Mileage 140000 km.
Navigation System: 
Cylinders 4
Central Lock: 
Gear Type Automatic
Hatch: 
Drive Wheels 4x4
Alarm: 
Doors 4/5
Board Computer: 
Wheel WHELL right
Hydraulics: 
Car color silver
Anti skid: 
Interior color grey
Chair Warming: 
Airbags 0
Parking Control: 
VIN 
უკანა ხედვის კამერა:
```

Or:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(h)

for row in soup.select("table tr"):
    a, b = row.select_one("th div.th-key"), row.select_one("th div.th-value")
    if a:
        print a.text.strip(),b.text.strip()
```

Which gives you:

```
Manufacturer NISSAN
Model X-Trail
Prod. Year 2002
Category Jeep
Fuel Type Gas/Petrol
Engine Volume 2000
Mileage 140000 km.
Cylinders 4
Gear Type Automatic
Drive Wheels 4x4
Doors 4/5
Wheel WHELL right
Car color silver
Interior color grey
Airbags 0
VIN
```

If you just want the th-value text from the th-left headers:

```
h = """<table>
<tr>
        <th class="th-left">
            <div class="th-key"> Manufacturer</div>
            <div class="th-value"> NISSAN</div>
        </th>
        <th class="th-right">
            <div class="th-key"> ABS</div>
            <div class="th-value"><i class='fa fa-check'></i></div>
        </th>
        </tr>
    <tr>
    <th class="th-left">
        <div class="th-key"> Model</div>
        <div class="th-value"> X-Trail </div>
    </th>
    <th class="th-right">
        <div class="th-key"> El. Windows</div>
        <div class="th-value"><i class='fa fa-check'></i></div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="th-left">
        <div class="th-key"> Prod. Year</div>
        <div class="th-value"> 2002</div>
    </th>
    <th class="th-right">
        <div class="th-key"> Air Condintioner</div>
        <div class="th-value"><i class='fa fa-check'></i></div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>"""
```

Using the html above:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(h)

print([d.text.strip() for d in soup.select("table tr th.th-left div.th-value")])
```

Gives you:

```
[u'NISSAN', u'X-Trail ', u'2002']
```

Comment: Dear @Padraic Cunnigham i explained a bit briefly what i want to achieve can you take a look . thanks

Comment: So you only want th-value?

Comment: i want to put th-value to list like this data = ['NISSAN','X-Trail','2002','Jeep','Gas/Petrol','2000','140000 km.','4','Automatic','4x4','4/5','WHELL right','color silver','color grey','0
','' ] but thats only one car.so i can insert them to sqlite db. with this code conn.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",data)

Comment: Just insert as you go

Comment: thank you, can you explain me why this:

for d in soup.select("table tr th.th-left div.th-value"): 
   print([d.text.strip()])

does not equal to this : 

print([d.text.strip() for d in soup.select("table tr th.th-left div.th-value")])